# How to insert NULL into database if form field is empty

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a form and stored procedure that inserts the data from the form. It works fine except that if a field isn't filled in it doesn't insert a `NULL` into SQL it inserts `""`.

I've tried a few different ways but none seem to insert `NULL`, the one below still inserts `""`, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Here is the required part of the code, if you require more just let me know.

```
Dim rdr As SqlDataReader
            Dim cmdInsert As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()
            cmdInsert.CommandText = "spPersonalDetailsInsert"
            cmdInsert.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmdInsert.Connection = connSQL


            Dim firstname, lastname, address, address1, town, county, postcode As SqlParameter
            'convert to null if ""
            Dim frmFirstName As String
            If pd_first_name.Text = "" Then
                frmFirstName = Convert.DBNull
            Else
                frmFirstName = pd_first_name.Text
            End If

            firstname = New SqlParameter()
            firstname.ParameterName = "@firstname"
            firstname.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar
            firstname.Size = 50
            firstname.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
            firstname.Value = frmFirstName
```

**EDIT**

I tested the following code:

```
If pd_first_name.Text = "" Then
            frmFirstName = DBNull.Value
        Else
            frmFirstName = pd_first_name.Text
        End If
```

But it still doesn't insert `NULL` so I tested this:

```
            If pd_first_name.Text = "" Then
                Response.Write("NULL")
                address1.Value = DBNull.Value
            Else
                Response.Write("NOT NULL")
                address1.Value = pd_address1.Text
            End If
```

So if I enter nothing into `address1` field it should write `NULL` to screen but it always writes `NOT NULL`. What does an empty form field equal? in classic ASP it was always `""`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to use [DBNull.Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value.aspx)

```
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(pd_first_name.Text.ToString().Trim) = true Then
                frmFirstName = DBNull.Value
            Else
                frmFirstName = pd_first_name.Text
            End If
```

Comment: I just tested above and it still doesn't insert NULL, see edited question above, thanks.

Comment: This does work actually, my fault, i was referencing the wrong form field in my edited code, thanks Barry.

Answer (score 3):

In my case using **'Nothing'** solves the problem. Use it like this

```
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(pd_first_name.Text) = True Then
   frmFirstName = Nothing
Else
   frmFirstName = pd_first_name.Text
End If
```

Comment: This was also how I had to solve my problem. For some reason DBNull.Value doesn't work with DateTime fields

Answer (score 1):

why you even set it if it is null?

```
        If pd_first_name.Text <> "" Then
          frmFirstName = pd_first_name.Text
          firstname = New SqlParameter()
          firstname.ParameterName = "@firstname"
          firstname.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar
          firstname.Size = 50
          firstname.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
          firstname.Value = frmFirstName
        End If
```

Comment: Its a form item, if nothing is entered it equals "" not NULL.

Answer (score 0):

I think you problem is that `frmFirstName` is a string and a string cannot represent DBNull.

I think this will solve your problem (I've just commented out your code):

```
Dim rdr As SqlDataReader
            Dim cmdInsert As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()
            cmdInsert.CommandText = "spPersonalDetailsInsert"
            cmdInsert.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmdInsert.Connection = connSQL


            Dim firstname, lastname, address, address1, town, county, postcode As SqlParameter
            'convert to null if ""
            Dim frmFirstName As String
            'If pd_first_name.Text = "" Then
            '    frmFirstName = Convert.DBNull
            'Else
            '    frmFirstName = pd_first_name.Text
            'End If

            firstname = New SqlParameter()
            firstname.ParameterName = "@firstname"
            firstname.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar
            firstname.Size = 50
            firstname.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
            If pd_first_name.Text = "" Then
                  firstname.Value = DBNull.Value
            Else
                  firstname.Value = frmFirstName
            End If
```

Answer (score 0):

While creating stored procedure make those columns as null which can be null..
like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_TDS_SaveRecod]

@ID INT,

@CODE  INT,

@FIRSTNAME VARCHAR(8)=NULL,

@CITY VARCHAR(15)=NULL

AS

BEGIN

    .........................

    .........................

    .........................
END
```

and then in code don't add those parameters which are null..

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = obj.ID;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@CODE", SqlDbType.Int).Value = obj.CODE;
if(pd_first_name.Text != "")
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@FIRSTNAME", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = pd_first_name.Text;
}
if(city.Text != "")
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@CITY", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = pd_first_name.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim TempStr As String
TempStr= "spPersonalDetailsInsert"
TempStr = TempStr.Replace("''", "null")
cmdInsert.CommandText = TempStr
```

Now No Need to use

```
If pd_first_name.Text = "" Then
   Response.Write("NULL")
   address1.Value = DBNull.Value
Else
   Response.Write("NOT NULL")
   address1.Value = pd_address1.Text
End If
```

Hope this might be Helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
If RdFree.Checked = True Then
    Dim nu As String = "NULL"
    UpdPolicys.Append(", AccIDFree = " & nu & " , AccTypeIDFree = " & nu & " ")
End If
```