# How to replace empty string parameter to Null in stored procedure and VB.net

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have stored procedure that allow null parameter and works fine in SSMS. .  Here is the SP

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_RepInventorySales]
@SalesOrderNo varchar(9) = null
AS
BEGIN
SELECT SalesOrderNo, ItemCode, ContainerNo, SealNo, ContainerType, OrderQty
FROM  SalesOrderDetail 
where SalesOrderNo = isnull(@SalesOrderNo, SalesOrderNo )
```

Actually the SP is the source of my crystal report. When Me.txtSalesOrderNo.Text is NOT empty I get the correct output.However, if textbox is empty, the stored procedure treats the parameter as empty string '' . How can i replace empty string to NULL? . Here is the code VB code

```
Private Dset As DataSet 
Private Da As SqlDataAdapter 

  Dim objRpt As New RepInventorySales /*used for crystal report*/
    Dset = New DataSet

Da = New SqlDataAdapter("sp_RepInventorySales '" & trim(Me.txtSalesOrderNo.Text) & "' ", Conn_DB)
 Da.Fill(Dset)
        If Dset.Tables(0).Rows.Count <> 0 Then
            objRpt.SetDataSource(Dset.Tables(0))
```

I tried to use IIF in query string in SqlDataAdapter to replace empty string to null but gives me error

```
            Da = New SqlDataAdapter("sp_RepInventorySales '" & Trim(Me.IIf(txtTextBox.Text Is Nothing, Null, txtTextBox.Text).Text) & "' ", Conn_DB)
```

This is the final solution. thank you for your help!

```
IF @SalesOrderNo = ''
    SET @SalesOrderNo = NULL
IF @ContainerType = ''
    SET @ContainerType = NULL

SELECT SalesOrderNo, ItemCode, ContainerNo, SealNo, ContainerType, OrderQty
FROM SalesOrderDetail
WHERE ( SalesOrderNo = @SalesOrderNo OR @SalesOrderNo IS NULL )
      AND
      ( ContainerType = @ContainerType OR @ContainerType IS NULL )
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert NULL into database if form field is empty using ASP.NET & VB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722705/how-to-insert-null-into-database-if-form-field-is-empty-using-asp-net-vb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just put the condition on your SP

```
   IF @SalesOrderNo = '' SET @SalesOrderNo = null 
   IF @ContainerType= '' SET @ContainerType= null 
   SELECT SalesOrderNo, ItemCode, ContainerNo, SealNo, ContainerType, OrderQty
   FROM  SalesOrderDetail 
   where SalesOrderNo = @SalesOrderNo AND ContainerType = @ContainerType
```

Comment: Single parameter is working but adding another parameter extracted no records.

Comment: what's the parameter you added? @Allan

Comment: the 2nd parameter is containertype which i just copy the same If and set statement and add where clause same as the salesorderno.

Comment: @Allan please see my edit. no need to add isnull on `where`.. then if there  are no result, the problem is in your data

Comment: The If  and set statements in SP. this is the shortest  way to replace '' string to null. This forum is amazing!!! Thanks zzzzzz and to you guys who spend time answering my query...    @Fabio@Japz Divino

Answer (score 1):

Use `DBNull.Value` instead.

**IF ELSE approach:** (*validate and assign before calling* `New SqlDataAdapter`, therefore no need an `IIF` inside the sql adapter, just assign the value of `textbox`)

```
 If String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSalesOrderNo.Text.ToString().Trim) = true Then
     txtSalesOrderNo.Text = DBNull.Value
 Else
     txtSalesOrderNo.Text = txtSalesOrderNo.Text
 End If
```

[How to insert NULL into database if form field is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722705/how-to-insert-null-into-database-if-form-field-is-empty-using-asp-net-vb)

[DBNull.Value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value.aspx)

Comment: It tried IIF approach but still textbox is showing '' empty string Me.txtSalesOrderNo.Text = IIf(Me.txtSalesOrderNo.Text Is Nothing, DBNull.Value, Trim(Me.txtSalesOrderNo.Text))
            Da = New SqlDataAdapter("sp_RepInventorySales '" & Trim(Me.txtSalesOrderNo.Text) & "' ", Conn_DB)

Comment: If Else approach gives me an error Value of type 'System.DBNull' cannot be converted to string

Comment: @Allan , alright .. just remove this `.ToString()` inside of this `String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSalesOrderNo.Text.ToString().Trim)` , just replace it by `String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSalesOrderNo.Text.Trim)` , because converting `DB NULL` values into string will get an error, i will modify the answer.

Comment: I remove as instructed but still the same eror ...If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Me.txtSalesOrderNo.Text.Trim) = True Then
                Me.txtSalesOrderNo.Text = DBNull.Value

Comment: `txtSalesOrderNo.Text = DBNull.Value` ain't possible

Answer (score 1):

You will always get empty string because you passing parameter as hardcoded string inside single quote `..."sp_RepInventorySales '" & trim(Me.txtSalesOrderNo.Text) & "'...`

Add parameter to the `SqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters` collection properly, then you can use `DBNull.Value`

```vb
Da = New SqlDataAdapter("sp_RepInventorySales", Conn_DB)
DA.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
'Parameter's type need to be Object because DBNull.Value cannot be converted to string
Dim paramValue as Object = DirectCast(DBNull.value, Object)
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Me.txtSalesOrderNo.Text) = false Then
    paramValue = Me.txtSalesOrderNo.Text.Trim()
End If
Dim param As New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@SalesOrderNo",
                                    .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar,
                                    .Value = paramValue}
DA.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(param)
Da.Fill(Dset)
```

Comment: _Side note_ : What's the point of using `@YourParameterName` because parameter name of proc `sp_RepInventorySales`is already visible in the question i.e `@SalesOrderNo`

Comment: This one works! although code is lengthy I just add another parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I've revamped your method with a solution, You can try this

```
  Sub fun()
        Dim Dset As DataSet
        Dim Da As PgSqlDataAdapter
        Dim strParam As Object
        Dim objRpt As New crptAccountlist
        Dset = New DataSet
        If Trim(txtSalesOrderNo.Text) <> vbNullString Then
            strParam = Trim(txtSalesOrderNo.Text)
        Else
            strParam = DBNull.Value
        End If
        Da = New PgSqlDataAdapter("", Conn_DB)
        With Da
            .SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            .SelectCommand.CommandText = "sp_RepInventorySales"
            .SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SalesOrderNo", strParam)
        End With
        Da.Fill(Dset)
    End Sub
```

---

See this [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hPcxvX)