# How to Check and enter the data from "2 Textboxes" based on the availablity of the data into access from VB .Net

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

I'm trying to insert some data into the access database but with some condition. Which is to enter the data by checking the **2 Textboxes** and only then insert into access database.

To brief you more, please check out my code..

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form1
Dim provider As String
Dim datafile As String
Dim connString As String
Dim myConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
Dim str As String
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="
    datafile = "D:\Database\samplech.accdb"
    connString = provider & datafile
    myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
    myConnection.Open()

    Dim chinsrt1 As String
    chinsrt1 = "Insert into bkCharacters([bkch01],[bkch02],[bkch03],[bkCh04]) Values (?,?,?,?)"
    Dim chcmd1 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(chinsrt1, myConnection)
    If (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CH1.Text)) Then
        If (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CHDP1.Text)) Then
            chcmd1.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("bk01", CType(bkNmbr.Text, String)))
            chcmd1.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("bk02", CType(CH1.Text, String)))
            chcmd1.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("bk03", CType(CHDP1.Text, String)))
            chcmd1.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("bk04", CType(CHSource.Text, String)))
        Else
            ' Insert an empty String
            chcmd1.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("bk01", ""))
            chcmd1.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("bk02", ""))
            chcmd1.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("bk03", ""))
            chcmd1.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("bk04", ""))
        End If
    End If


    Dim chinsrt2 As String
    chinsrt2 = "Insert into bkCharacters([bkch01],[bkch02],[bkch03],[bkCh04]) Values (?,?,?,?)"
    Dim chcmd2 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(chinsrt2, myConnection)
    If (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CH2.Text)) Then
        If (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CHDP2.Text)) Then
    chcmd2.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("bk01", CType(bkNmbr.Text, String)))
            chcmd2.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("bk02", CType(CH2.Text, String)))
            chcmd2.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("bk03", CType(CHDP2.Text, String)))
            chcmd2.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("bk04", CType(CHSource.Text, String)))
        Else
            ' Insert an empty String
            chcmd2.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("bk01", ""))
            chcmd2.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("bk02", ""))
            chcmd2.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("bk03", ""))
            chcmd2.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("bk04", ""))
        End If
    End If



    Try
        chcmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
        chcmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
        chcmd1.Dispose()
        chcmd2.Dispose()
        myConnection.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

What I'm trying to do here is to check the values of CH1.Text and CHDP1.Text and if there's some data in either one of those textboxes, i want the another field in access to be empty.

But If there's data in both of them just insert accordingly...

In both scenarios I want to also include bkNmbr.Text and ChSource.Text.

And If there's no data in both textboxes(CH1 and CHDP1), i just don't want to update the data at all (no update of the records)

Please help me out guys, I'm stuck here.

Thank You.

Comment: Are you looking for `DBNull.Value` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722705/how-to-insert-null-into-database-if-form-field-is-empty ?

Comment: No bro ... I don't have any problem entering null or empty values in Access Database... My concern is to "enter the data" based on the conditions i provided in the question.

Comment: So whats wrong? Your missing bk03 parameter in the `else`part, but you need it to match your queryparams.

Comment: brother please read my question again.... i want to check Ch1.Text and CHDP1.Text and then insert the data based on the conditions (the availability of data) i provided.

Comment: Sorry, now I see, your struggeling with the logic. Delete the Null String part, this is confusing.

Comment: ok bro... i deleted that part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if one field is not empty and then insert, if both empty do nothing.

```vb
If (Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CH1.Text)) OR (Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CHDP1.Text)) Then 'check if at least one field is not empty
  Dim checkNullCH1 as String
  Dim checkNullCHDP1 as String

  If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CH1.Text) then 'check if field is empty
    checkNullCH1 = "" 
  else 
    checkNullCH1 = CH1.Text
  end if

  If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CHPD1.Text) then
    checkNullCHPD1 = ""
  else 
    checkNullCHPD1 = CHPD1.Text
  end if
  chcmd1.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("bk01", CType(bkNmbr.Text, String)))
  chcmd1.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("bk02", CType(checkNullCH1, String)))
  chcmd1.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("bk03", CType(checkNullCHPD1, String)))
  chcmd1.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("bk04", CType(CHSource.Text, String)))
  chcmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
end if
```

Alternate you can check if both are empty.

```vb
If not ((String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CH1.Text)) AND (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CHDP1.Text))) Then
```

This is equal to the other one.

Comment: It's working bro, but it's inserting 2 rows into access, don't know why it's doing that and also another thing.... bkNmbr.Text will always have some data in it, but like i said in my question, if there's no data in CH1.Text and CHDP1.Text, I don't want to update that record at all (completely ignore it in access).... Given that i still have some data in bkNmbr.Text

Comment: You don't `UPDATE` records, you do an `INSERT`, so every column in a row needs a value (even `NULL` if no data). Did you remove the `chcmd2` part of your code, otherwise it executes twice.

Comment: The `If`statement prevents `INSERT` if both fields are empty, no matter what .`bkNmbr.Text` value is.

Comment: Yes bro, i have removed chcmd2 part of my code and still it executes twice... that is, it's inserting 2 rows with the same data... and also like i said if i have a value in just one textbox (bknmbr.Text) then i'm getting this error bro "No Value given for one or more required parameters" ..... Can u also please check with this issue bro

Comment: Edit your question and show the new code. Mark the line with the error and add complete error message (maybe you can't assing `DBNull.Value` to a string, change is to `""`). I'm from `MS-Access` vba which is slightly different (so I would check the `textboxes` with `Len(myTextBox.Text & "") > 0`).

Comment: I figured out what's causing the double entry bro, it's like you have included the "chcmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()" in the IF statement itself and I have "chcmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()" in the Try Statement too. Now I just kept only one, and it's working really great bro... can u please check with bkNmbr.Text issue bro, it's just that even if i don't have any data in either Ch1.Text or CHDP1.Text (both are blank), it should not try to enter the data into access

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114920/discussion-between-bitaccesser-and-winnu).